# Отображение тэгов с контентом и без

Tags: html, css

Почему в примере ниже тэги с текстом и без текста размещаются на разной высоте? Чем обусловлено такое поведение?

HTML код:

```css
.sq {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test1 {
  background: yellow;
}

#test2 {
  background: red
}

.hs {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test1" class="sq"></div>
  <div id="test2" class="sq">text</div>

  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
  <h1 class="hs"></h1>
  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

По умолчании для display:inline-block; стоить выравнивание по baseline 
чтоб выровнять их по линии необходимо дописать vertical-align:top;

```css
.sq {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#test1 {
  background: yellow;
}

#test2 {
  background: red
}

.hs {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test1" class="sq"></div>
  <div id="test2" class="sq">text</div>

  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
  <h1 class="hs"></h1>
  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
  <h1 class="hs">text</h1>
</body>
```